# How to interpret and fix 'shared object not found' error when importing library in R on MacOS in a conda environment?

Tags: python, r, macos, conda, rpy2

I am attempting to import an R package from a specific R path in a conda environment, but I keep receiving the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘marginaleffects’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
shared object ‘data_table.so’ not found
```

I am struggling to understand not just how to fix this error, but also what this error means or where it is coming from.

Specifically, I am deploying a web application with the Python-based `streamlit` framework and am using the package `rpy2` to interface from an existing R codebase to Python. I use conda/mamba as the package manager on my machine. I have installed all R packages using their conda-forge distribution as possible. There are several R packages that are not available, so I have installed them in R to the path of my desired library with with: `install.packages("marginaleffects", dep = TRUE, lib = "/Users/myuser/mambaforge/envs/myenv/lib/R/library", verbose = TRUE)`. The package then appears to exist in the directory `.../myenv/lib/R/library`, in `installed.packages()`, and in RStudio's list of packages.

However, when I attempt to load the package with `library(marginaleffects, lib.loc="/Users/myuser/mambaforge/envs/myenv/lib/R/library")` I receive the error noted above. Note that if I import this Packages in an R code run in the streamlit app, it raises a slightly different error relating to a `.dylib` shared object, instead of an '.so` shared object.

```
RRuntimeError: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘marginaleffects’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib): shared object ‘marginaleffects.dylib’ not found
```

I have the vaguest sense this has something to do with a compiler error. I have also been unsuccessful in installing the package through the `rpy2` framework, receiving a long and fairly inscrutable error message.

**EDIT**

The code I have run so far for reproducibility on a MacOS (Ventura, same issue happened on Big Sur):

```
zsh> mamba create -n myenv r-essentials r-base python=3.8
zsh> mamba activate myenv
zsh> mamba install -c r rpy2 
zsh> mamba install -c conda-forge pandas
zsh> mamba install -c conda-forge streamlit

R> install.packages("clarify", dep = TRUE, lib = "/Users/myname/mambaforge/envs/myenv/lib/R/library", verbose = TRUE)
R> install.packages("marginaleffects", dep = TRUE, lib = "/Users/myname/mambaforge/envs/myenv/lib/R/library", verbose = TRUE)
R> library(marginaleffects, lib.loc="/Users/myuser/mambaforge/envs/myenv/lib/R/library")
```

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘marginaleffects’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
shared object ‘data_table.so’ not found
```

**EDIT2**

I am running osx-64.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571407/r-package-installation-fails-cant-find-existing-dylib](Other question) could be usefull info.

Comment: This is too vague. Please create a minimal example that others can recreate the issue with. Typically, [DLL issues can arise from mixing channels](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels), but it's not clear that applies here. Is everything installed with Conda? or was `install.packages` used? (it generally shouldn't be)

Comment: Thanks @merv. I have added the code run so far to reproduce the issue. If not install.packages, how would you add a package to a conda/mamba environment when it does not have a conda distribution?

Comment: I have directions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69921221/570918). I'm on the Conda Forge R team, so if you ever have hiccups getting something added there, just ping me (**@mfansler** on GH). Definitely `marginaleffects` is available already (`r-marginaleffects`) and I'll add `clarify` for you (`r-clarify`). Note that CRAN packages are always prefixed with `r-` and converted to lowercase.

Comment: Many thanks @merv! The `r-clarify` package was available for download. Unfortunately, I receive the message `Could not solve for environment specs
The following package could not be installed` with a package tree. When I attempt to install the basal package in the tree, I get the same error with `The following package could not be installed
└─ llvm-tools 13.0.1**  is requested and can be installed`. Is this (potentially) related to the `r-clarify` build or is this likely a deeper issue? (I'm not seeing an obvious answer online for what this error means.)

Comment: You should not be using the `r` channel - only `conda-forge`. However, that still ends in error, so I gave an answer. Basically, still need `r-mvnfast` to be built for **osx-arm64**. Such migrations are highly variable in turnaround time, but I'll try to swing back with updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recreate the issue on **osx-arm64** platform (note that everything works fine for **osx-64**):

**so-rpy2-clarify.yaml**

```yaml
name: so-rpy2-clarify
channels:
  - conda-forge  # only Conda Forge
  - nodefaults   # ignore user config
dependencies:
  ## Python
  - python=3.8
  - rpy2
  - pandas
  - streamlit

  ## R
  - r-base=4.3  # always define R version
  - r-clarify
  - r-essentials
  - r-marginaleffects
```

which running with:

```bash
mamba env create -f so-rpy2-clarify.yaml
```

gives:

```bash
Could not solve for environment specs
The following package could not be installed
└─ r-clarify is not installable because it requires
   └─ r-mvnfast, which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel).
```

This package isn't yet being built for **osx-arm64**, but [we can put in a request](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge-pinning-feedstock/pull/4652) (see [the documentation on *"Apple Silicon Builds"*](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html#apple-silicon-builds)).

Let's also check to make sure nothing else also is needed, since the conflict reporting usually just reports the first problem. We use `mamba repoquery` for this:

```bash
mamba repoquery depends -c conda-forge -p osx-arm64 r-clarify

Executing the query r-clarify

conda-forge/osx-arm64                                       Using cache
conda-forge/noarch                                          Using cache


 Name                        Version Build             Channel    
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 r-clarify                   0.1.3   r42hc72bb7e_0     conda-forge
 r-rlang                     0.4.11  r40h6f62c66_0     conda-forge
 r-ggplot2                   3.1.0   r351h6115d3f_1000 conda-forge
 r-pbapply                   1.3_4   r351h6115d3f_1000 conda-forge
 r-mvnfast >>> NOT FOUND <<<                                      
 r-base                      4.2.3   heabe65b_0        conda-forge
 r-chk                       0.9.0   r43hc72bb7e_1     conda-forge
 r-insight                   0.19.3  r43hc72bb7e_0     conda-forge
 r-marginaleffects           0.9.0   r42hc72bb7e_0     conda-forge
```

Looks like `r-mvnfast` is the only missing dependency.

Comment: Huge thanks @merv! I just tried this and it worked for me. I'll just add that I was having the problem posted above even with osx-64 (which I will edit my post to specify). I think for me the fix may have been something as simple as specifying the R version or avoiding defaults.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @merv's answer above, which I have accepted, I was able to resolve this issue with a slightly different approach by doing two things. This may be helpful for anyone troubleshooting a similar problem.

1. *Sequencing*: Installing `streamlit` last and using `pip` instead of `conda`. Once I had installed all the other required packages, I could not get conda to find a compatible distribution of streamlit. Installing with pip seems to work fine, however.
2. *Consistency in installation*: Installing all R packages through `conda` (technically `mamba`) instead of  `install.packages` in R. (Thanks again to @merv for rapidly getting `r-clarify` up.)